# Memory leak during seeding about 1000000 items using factories

Tags: php, laravel

I've simple seeder

```
    $count = 10000;

    $this->command->withProgressBar(array_fill(1, $count, ''),function ($item) {
        $terms = Term::factory(10)->create();
        $terms->each(function ($term) {
            $term->questions()->saveMany(
                Question::factory(10)->make(['term_id' => $term->id])
            );
        });
    });
```

But I always got memory leak "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16384 bytes) in ....public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 495 arout `$i = 2000`

I can increase memory limit, but don't userstand which sections harm memory so much, because I rewrite `$terms` on every iteration

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As i see it you are creating a so-called 1+n issue. When you run over the foreach loop 10000 times and make a new Question, you are bottlenecking your database.

The database is responding slower than your php process.

You might need to take a different approach, with batching, or batch inserts.

Comment: I tried and meet the same issue without withProgressBar(